# Using Facets in the Aggregation Framework C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to create an Aggregation on my data to get the total amount of counts for specific tags for a collection of books in my .Net application.

I have the following Book class.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And when the data is saved, it is stored in the following format in MongoDB.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("574325a36fdc967af03766dc"), 
    "Name" : "My First Book", 
    "Tags" : {
        "Edition" : "First", 
        "Type" : "HardBack", 
        "Published" : "2017", 
    }
}
```

I've been using facets directly in MongoDB and I am able to get the results that I need by using the following query:

```
db.{myCollection}.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "Name" : "SearchValue"
            }
        },
        {
            $facet: {
                 "categorizedByTags" : [ 
                     {   
                       $project :
                       { 
                         Tags: { $objectToArray: "$Tags" }
                       }
                     },
                     { $unwind : "$Tags"},
                     { $sortByCount : "$Tags"}
                  ]

            }
        },
    ]
);
```

However I am unable to transfer this over to the .NET C# Driver for Mongo. How can I do this using the .NET C# driver?

**Edit** - I will ultimately be looking to query the DB on other properties of the books as part of a faceted book listings page, such as Publisher, Author, Page count etc... hence the usage of $facet, unless there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would personally not use `$facet` here since you've only got one pipeline which kind of defeats the purpose of `$facet` in the first place...

The following is simpler and scales better (`$facet` will create one single potentially massive document).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "Name" : "My First Book"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "Tags": {
            $objectToArray: "$Tags"
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Tags"
}, {
    $sortByCount: "$Tags"
}, {
    $group: { // not really needed unless you need to have all results in one single document
        "_id": null,
        "categorizedByTags": {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: { // not really needed, either: remove _id field
        "_id": 0
    }
}])
```

This could be written using the C# driver as follows:

```
var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Book>("test");

var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(b => b.Name == "My First Book")
    .Project("{Tags: { $objectToArray: \"$Tags\" }}")
    .Unwind("Tags")
    .SortByCount<BsonDocument>("$Tags");

var output = pipeline.ToList().ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings {Indent = true});

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Here's the version using a facet:

```
var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Book>("test");

var project = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project<Book, BsonDocument>("{Tags: { $objectToArray: \"$Tags\" }}");
var unwind = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Unwind<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>("Tags");
var sortByCount = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.SortByCount<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>("$Tags");

var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Book, AggregateSortByCountResult<BsonDocument>>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] { project, unwind, sortByCount });

// string based alternative version
//var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Book, BsonDocument>.Create(
//    "{ $project :{ Tags: { $objectToArray: \"$Tags\" } } }",
//    "{ $unwind : \"$Tags\" }",
//    "{ $sortByCount : \"$Tags\" }");

var facetPipeline = AggregateFacet.Create("categorizedByTags", pipeline);

var aggregation = collection.Aggregate().Match(b => b.Name == "My First Book").Facet(facetPipeline);

var output = aggregation.Single().Facets.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { Indent = true });

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: We plan on using a facet due to needing to make other queries on other properties (not mentioned in the earlier question to simplify the example) such as Publisher, Author etc...

We are looking to change existing Aggregations in the project to use facets to reduce the total amount of DB calls for our faceted navigation on our book listings page.

Comment: @Adzy_12: Have you seen my updated answer which explains the $facet part?